# Running Argon2 WASM in browser

Tags: javascript, webassembly

Playing around with web crypto, I've downloaded *argon2.wasm* and *argon2.js* from [argon2-browser](https://github.com/antelle/argon2-browser) and am now trying to call them from JS using the introductory example:

```
argon2.hash({pass: 'password', salt: 'somesalt', distPath: 'dist'}).then(console.log);
```

However, this results in the following error and warnings (in Firefox):

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: argon2 is not defined
wasm streaming compile failed: TypeError: WebAssembly: Response has unsupported MIME type '' expected 'application/wasm' argon2.js:1:10104
falling back to ArrayBuffer instantiation
```

I've searched around for a while now but have failed to find an answer. What am I missing?